# MS Project resource graph across multiple projects

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning, gantt

I am using MS Project to create Gantt charts for multiple projects. Each project consists of different resources but these resources are shared across all of these projects.

Currently these resources have overlapped but I can't find some visual graph where I can see specific resources are overlapping and where I can also see in which project.

I have managed to find a view called Resource graph; it shows a graph with workers and when they are overbooked. However I can't see in which projects these resources are overlapping.

Can you please help with suggestions on how to do this in MS Project or some other type of software?

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a shared resource pool, as described here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-share-a-resource-pool-64a2416e-b811-4ddf-b039-e0347e233581

Basically you have one project file with resources that you link to from your other project files. If you already have project files in use, this will require a bunch of initial setup..